# Redirect users to different domains of the same web application according to their ip address location

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker

I have to internationalize my web application to different countries i have 4 domains corresponding to each country how can i use nginx to detect visitor ip address and redirect them to the correct domain by their ip and if they join from another country which i don't support redirect them to my "default domain"

I have the current nginx.conf file

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
charset_types text/xml text/plain text/vnd.wap.wml application/x-javascript application/rss+xml text/css application/javascript application/json;
passenger_root /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.24;
passenger_ruby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby;

geoip_country /usr/local/nginx/GeoIP.dat;
geoip_city    /usr/local/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;

fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION_NAME $geoip_region_name;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_AREA_CODE $geoip_area_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;


#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

map $geoip_country_code $subdomain {
default es;
RU ru;
ES es;
   DE de;
}

#gzip  on;

server {

listen          80;
server_name  www.myserver.com;
root    /usr/local/nginx/html;
index   index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            root /usr/local/nginx/html;
            index index.php;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
         include fastcgi_params;
        }
}

upstream ru.server {
        server  www.example1.com;
}

upstream en.server {
        server  www.example2.com;
}

upstream default.server {
        server  wwww.example3.com;
}



# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}
```

}

How can i use the

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://$subdomain.my-domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
```

Comment: When you say “internationalize”, are you talking about presenting content in different languages? If so, doing that based on IP is rather nonsense – that I’m sitting in an internet cafe in China doesn’t mean I speak Chinese. The `Accept-Language` header is the first thing you should be looking at. And you should still allow the user to choose the language themselves (switch to a different version, without being automatically redirected away from there again.)

Comment: no i actually want to redirect to diferent nginx servers, diferent domains etc, besides language that is controlled by i18 library from php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GeoIP module - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html

In your config create a map like this

```
map $geoip_country_code $subdomain {
    default en;
    RU ru;
    ES es;
    DE de;
}
```

Then you can redirect, but an actual rule depends on your server-side. 
Example:

```
http {
    # ...

    map $geoip_country_code $subdomain {
        default en;
        RU ru;
        ES es;
        DE de;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.myserver.com;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ $scheme://$subdomain.myserver.com$request_uri? permanent;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously there should be a config for every subdomain (`en.myserver.com`, `ru.myserver.com`, ...). It can be one server section for one subdomain or for all of them at once.

```
server {
    server_name en.myserver.com, ru.myserver.com, ...
}
```

When user visits your `http://www.myserver.com/` GeoIP matches its IP, then `map` maps country code (let it be 'RU') to a subdomain. After that you have a string with subdomain in your `$subdomain` variable. Then you can use that variable as you want. `rewrite` makes redirect from current location to `$subdomain.myserver.com` which is actually `ru.myserver.com` in our example.

`default` in `map` is for default value, if none from the left side was matched.

Comment: im kinda new to nginx this rewrite rules should be add on the config file or where?

Comment: your `.conf` file should hold the changes

Comment: im using docker to setup the environment  any clue how to change the config file in this scenario?

Comment: I think you should use local configuration mapped to docker, like `docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro`

Comment: i have a container already but i didnt made it myself so how could i just edit the config file on a existing docker container?

Comment: hey i made it till now i need to include and compile de module GeoIP  into mi nginx is saw i need to add this --with-http_geoip_module into ./configure, i dont understand what they mean by this can u help me out to compile this module on my nginx! thannks

Comment: I think you should ask another question on SO :)

Comment: hey i finally manged to do it but i ahve this problem now i get this after setting the map above nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "map" directive in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:37

Comment: Please update your question with your current configuration including map part. Also, what's your nginx version?

Comment: Place map into server block.

Comment: should i get a server block for every domain i have?

Comment: i got this when i put it into server block :P [emerg] "map" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:58

Comment: I'm sorry, map should be inside http context as in your first example config. But I don't know why you get `invalid number of arguments in "map"`. What's your nginx version?

Comment: is 1.6.3 but i already fixed that problem now i don't know how to use the rewrite can u explain me a little what the map does exactly what value does $subdomain gets in the end? and whats the rewrite for thanks!