# Routing to different subdomains based on geo location

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, nginx, geolocation

I am having a default domain example.com. what i am looking to do is to route the request to subdomains based on the geolocation.
I have created multiple subdomains like

```
us.example.com  --> US                     
au.example.com  ---> Australia           
in.example.com ----> India
```

my application is running in docker and i am routing the request with reverse proxy. i am having below nginx config file.

```
map $geoip_country_code $subdomain { 
 default def;
  US      us;
  AU      au;
  RU      ru;
  IN      in;
}

server {
server_name example.com
            us.example.com
            au.example.com
            ru.example.com
            in.example.com
            def.example.com;

#if ($closest_server != $host) {
#    rewrite ^ $scheme://$closest_server$request_uri break;
#  }

location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  #proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
  #client_max_body_size 0;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$subdomain.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                 expires 365d;
        }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;
}
```

though i hit the domain with default example.com its not routing correctly. it would be great if someone get give the inputs since i am
new to nginx routing.

similar request: [Redirect users to different domains of the same web application according to their ip address location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207251/redirect-users-to-different-domains-of-the-same-web-application-according-to-the)